# Slick advertising campaigns, soaring gold prices and increasing purchasing power for consumers have helped develop a market for diamonds.

Tags: exam-questions

> Slick advertising campaigns, soaring gold prices and increasing purchasing power for consumers have helped develop a market for diamonds.

This sentence is from an error spotting exercise which suggests to use *diamond* in place of *diamonds*. May I know why diamonds is wrong here ? Moreover isn't the *for* used in the sentence wrong here ? *Of* would have been better in place of *for* I.e. *purchasing power of consumers* .

Comment: For some reason I would prefer  "*increased* purchasing power" though.

Answer (score 1):

I would use *diamonds*. But I think it is splitting hairs in a case where the sentence would be understood either way.

In a strict sense, *diamond* in the example  is being used to describe a commodity, which tend to be uncountable. For example in "investing in gold", the quantity is unknown.

But unlike *gold* (you wouldn't say *golds*), *diamonds* are discrete objects, so most people would think of them as countable.

So in regular usage, I think most people would say *diamonds*.

Instead, I would prefer  "*increased* purchasing power".
*increasing* implies a changing state (though we have no reference or implication something is changing), while *increased* implies a more fixed wealthier condition.

The *for* is OK where it is, because the items mentioned are *for* the benefit of consumers.